# How Do you complete Memory Block 3?

Tags: assassins-creed

After defeating Talal, I'm wandering around this level for quite a while without any clue in how I can complete Jerusalem.

What should I do?

Comment: Are you anonymous? Have you made it back to assassins' home base?

Comment: Yes, i am always anonymous, but how does that help me?

Comment: + I did pay a visit with the assassin bureau

Answer (score 1):

After assassinating Talal, going back to the bureau and speaking with the bureau leader,  if you are done with Acre, go back to Masyaf to speak to Mualim.

Comment: IIRC, you have to do this sort of thing a lot.

Answer (score 1):

here is video. you can see what to do:

Here's how to complete all memories, from [supercheats.com](http://www.supercheats.com/guides/assassins-creed/memoryblock3.shtml):

> Acre Investigations
>
> Memory Strand 3 - Pickpocket South: Scale the View Point northwest of the Assassin’s Bureau to mark the location of this investigation on your map. There are two men conversing in a narrow tunnel. You’ll have to get past a couple of guards if you take the direct route. Stand near the tunnel south of their location. Blend while the letter carrier approaches. Turn around and pickpocket him when he walks past you. You learn of a possible connection between Garnier and your target in Jerusalem, Talal.

Comment: Can you add a short description of what happens in the video too? If the video ever goes away we still know what needs to be done then.

Comment: If you're just going to [copy and paste from another website](http://www.supercheats.com/guides/assassins-creed/memoryblock3.shtml), you had better add attribution to it.  It's plagiarizing, otherwise, and we seriously frown on that.  We also don't want people to just copy and paste stuff from other places; add a little bit of your own words.

Comment: well sorry about that but im new. i dont know many about this site so. i will learn. ty

Comment: Not a problem; that's why I'm explaining it to you.  So please add the attribution to your answer, and add some stuff in your own words.